# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)$ and $a$ be a constant with $y=g(x)=a$. ..

Tags: statistics, expectation

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)$ and $a$ be a constant with $y=g(x)=a$.

Find $E(y)$ using the formula $$E(g(x)) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty...\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x_1,...,x_p)f_x(x_1,...,x_p) dx_1...dx_p$$

Should there be a change of variable? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: If $g(x) = a,$ then $E(g(X)) = E(a) = a.$ In general, $E(bX + c) = bE(X)+c.$ But I'm not 100% sure I'm answering your real question. If not, please leave me a Comment.

Comment: @BruceET How would I show it using the formula I just added in? would it just be $$E(g(x))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty a (f_x(x)) dx = a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_x(x) dx= a (1) = a$$

Comment: That seems to do it.